# android - download file with retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2, download

I am using retrofit 2.0 for download a file.the problem is `enqueue` method not called. there is no error and no catch. nothing happen, where is my mistake?

this is my interface:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("uploads/{file_name}")
    Call<ServerResponse> downloadFile(@Path("file_name") String fileName);
}
```

and this is my downloading code :

```
private void downloadFile() {
        progressDialog.show();

        // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
        File file = new File(mediaPath);

        // Parsing any Media type file
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        ApiService getResponse = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.downloadFile(file.getName());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                if (serverResponse != null) {
                    if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    assert serverResponse != null;
                    Log.v("Response", serverResponse.toString());
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: how are you passing value for file name in your interface ?

Comment: using @path annotation , in its argument

Comment: Try using observable instead of Call

Comment: how can I do that? can u give me some explain?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are referring that the method "enqueue()" is called, but it's not the onResponse one.

Please wait some time (a minute is fine) and make sure that onResponse nor onFailure are called.

If you want more info, you can use the [HTTP logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor)

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST("uploads/{file_name}")
    Observable<Document> getDocumentsList(@Path("file_name") String fileName);
```

and the code webservice call should be

```
 Observable<Document> listObservable = mApiService.getDocumentsList(path);
    subscribe(listObservable, new Consumer<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Document resourceDtos) throws Exception {
            fillDocs(resourceDtos.getData());
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            fillDocs(throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });
```